# How to batch generate preview for multiple versions of filters/layers applied for the same image in Photoshop?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, photo-editing, batch, automation

Recently I'm experimenting a lot with postproduction, to look for some new style. I find it very tedious to check out various combinations of adjustment layers (also with various opacity), blending modes, LUT's etc.

I even prepared a special .psd with a big number of layers which I just toggle on and off but I still find it ineffective.

I would like to be able to batch generate a whole series of the same image with different effects, to the different degree applied. I haven't found anything suitable for this, just 'batch' options but for different image files. Have I overlooked something or the only way is to record a loooong action, which will apply various adjustments and save the images during the process? 
I thought it would be a natural option to generate previews of the image with different LUTs for instance but haven't found anything..

Comment: What does the structure of your file look like?

Comment: Do you mean the structure of my 'psd template' ?  This is just a stack of numerous layers, each layer using different effect separately (for instance there is a layer for given LUT file with opacity 20%, then for the same LUT 50%, then another layer with contrast bumped up/down) etc..  After basic adjustments in Camera Raw I put the photo in this document as smart object, and toggle layers visiblity on, and off, to see the effect. Much faster than applying effects by hand every time, but still time-consuming.

Comment: Yea, that's what I meant. I'm trying to think how I'd batch it and wanted to understand if each layer was it's own final "image" or if you had used adjustment layers/smart objects to where the toggle plays into the final "image". Sorry for being short - was on mobile and it was early.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you go to Filter > Filter Gallery, it gives a preview of the different filter effects before actually processing it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: that is somewhat useful, but not really fitting my needs - I need a view of multiple layers toggled visible/invisible, and this previews only filter effects